# Entity Framework - Attach entity Error when creating Parent Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am receiving the following error

> "Attaching an entity of type 'Datos.Medico' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate."

The error occurs when I try to attach an entity to the context as follows:

```
public override void Alta(Medico medico)
{
    foreach (Especialidad especialidad in medico.Especialidad)
    {
        this.context.Especialidad.Attach(especialidad);
    }
    base.Alta(medico);
}
```

The `Especialidad` entity is obtain as not tracking, as It is used to populate a combo:

```
public List<Especialidad> ObtenerEspecialidades()
{
    var especialidades = context.Especialidad.AsNoTracking();
    /*
    var especialidades = from unaEspecialidad in context.Especialidad
                         select unaEspecialidad;
                         */

    return especialidades.ToList();
}
```

And Then taken from the combo and added to the `Medico` entity, which contains a `List<Especialidad>`.

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

I am including the Entities definition as requested:

```
    public Medico()
    {
        this.Agenda = new HashSet<Agenda>();
        this.Historia_Clinica_Elemento = new HashSet<HistoriaClinicaElemento>();
        this.Turno = new HashSet<Turno>();
        this.Especialidad = new HashSet<Especialidad>();
        this.Espera_Atencion = new HashSet<EsperaAtencion>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Matricula { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TipoDocumento { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> Numero_Documento { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Fecha_Nacimiento { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Direccion { get; set; }
    public string Usuario { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Agenda> Agenda { get; set; }
    public virtual Direccion Direccion1 { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<HistoriaClinicaElemento> Historia_Clinica_Elemento { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Turno> Turno { get; set; }
    public virtual TipoDocumento Tipo_Documento { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Especialidad> Especialidad { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario Usuario1 { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<EsperaAtencion> Espera_Atencion { get; set; }
```

Especialidad:

```
public partial class Especialidad
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Especialidad()
    {
        this.Medico = new HashSet<Medico>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Medico> Medico { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how long your DbContext is kept open, it can be already associated with an entity. For instance if you are iterating through a set of Medico's and two have the same Espacialidad associated, the first will attach, while the second throws an error.

Before attaching an entity to a DbContext you should always check whether the entity is already attached:

```
foreach (Especialidad especialidad in medico.Especialidad)
{
     if (!this.context.Especialidad.Local.Any(x => x == especialidad))        
         this.context.Especialidad.Attach(especialidad);
}
```

Edit: For a many to many without bi-directional references.

Remove the collection Medico from Especialidad

Where you would currently map doctors as something like:

```
HasMany(x => x.Especialidad)
    .WithMany(x => x.Medico)
    .Map(x => 
    { 
       x.ToTable("Medico_Especialidad");
       x.MapLeftKey("MedicoID");
       x.MapRightKey("EspecialidadID");
    });
```

... this would change to:

```
HasMany(x => x.Especialidad)
    .WithMany() // Note the empty return reference.
    .Map(x => 
    { 
       x.ToTable("Medico_Especialidad");
       x.MapLeftKey("MedicoID");
       x.MapRightKey("EspecialidadID");
    });
```

Any code that you might have to get doctors by specialty that might be using Especialidad.Medico will need to be changed to resolve from the Doctor side I.e.

instead of:

`var medicos = context.Especialidad.Find(especialidadID).Medico`

would look something like:

`var medicos = context.Medico.Where(x => x.Especialidad.Any(e => e.ID == especialidadID)).ToList();`

When it comes to many-to-many or many-to-one relationships, to keep code simpler and avoid reference mix-ups it's generally advisable to avoid bi-directional references unless they are absolutely needed.  Part of the trouble that bi-directional references bring is that when A references a B, and B references an A, you need to ensure that the context resolves the exact same A and B on both sides. When detaching and re-attaching entities to the context this will cause grief either with association errors or duplicate PK insert errors.

Comment: I added this check, It seems like the entity is not in the context.When trying to add it same error.

Comment: Check your references between entities. The error is about attaching Medico, so if Especialidad holds a reference back to a Medico you should check that the reference is the same instance that the DbContext knows about.  Detaching and re-attaching entities easily gets messy. You may need to check Medico and Especialidads by ID against the Locals because it looks like it's got local copies of one or more entities you are trying to attach.

Comment: Actually The entity "Medico" has not been attached. This error is generated inside the "Create Medico" method. So, At the moment, the "medico" is not supposed to exist at all.

Comment: Can you update your code example to include the entity definitions for Medico and Especialidad, and the method where the exception is raised.

Comment: Thanks. Ok, so the relationship between Medico (doctor) and Especialidad (specialty) is a many to many? There would be a joining table like MedicoEspecialidad? Normally for a relationship like that I would treat the Specialty as a lookup with the relationship mapped in a single direction from Doctor. (Removing the Medico collection in Especialidad.) It would still be many-to-many but without the bi-directional reference. Use a break-point to look before the exception whether the specialty is referencing other doctors.

Comment: That´s correct, It´s a many to many, with a joining table called "Medico_Especialidad". I will check if the specialty points to others Doctors, but It probably does. Is It posible to remove the bi directional reference without modifing the DB structure?

Comment: Yes, you can remove the bidirectional in the entity without affecting schema. Updated details in answer.

Comment: I could not find the mapping, I believe that's for Code First.